# Which book should I use?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

I am going to take PChem I in my biochem dept next sem, which is a watered down version of the PChem course in Chem dept. It basically covers thermodynamics and a little bit of quantum stuff. The syllabus says there is no required text, since course notes will be available once we register for class. But I do want to get ahead of class by reading books. I have several books at hand, please give me suggestions on which one should I use and if you have any good free lectures, feel free to post links as well.I don't feel like a need a Quantum Chem Book, given that how little quantum is actually covered.

Intro to Molecular thermodynamics by Hanson&Green, PChem for Chem and BioSci by Chang,Pchem by Castellan.Molecular Driving Forces by Dill&Bromberg, PChem: A molecular approach by McQuarrie, An introduction to thermal physics by Schroeder, Callen's thermodynamics text and also Fermi's.

Personally, I found Hanson, Castellan, Dill, and Chang are pretty good, haven't read any other

Comment: This seems off-topic. Highly opinion-based, there is no "right" answer. You probably won't get much of an answer.

Comment: I am new here so sorry If I dont understand the  rule properly. But in fact I dont wnat the "right" answer, because I know there isnn't one. All I want is an answer or  some answers. Like someone could come up and say McQuarrie's book is not good for beginner's because of A B and C. Schroeder's book has good features such as this and that. Answers like this is good enough for me.

Comment: @Zeyuan, the problem is that answers like this aren't good enough for this site. See [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), specifically a statement on chatty, open-ended questions.

Comment: But you're always welcome with such *chat*ty questions in our [*chat* room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229/the-periodic-table).

Comment: Try out Atkins, Physical Chemistry for the Life Sciences? http://www.amazon.co.uk/Physical-Chemistry-Sciences-Peter-Atkins/dp/0199564280 I can't guarantee you will like it, but it suits your needs. Wild meow is right, come over to chat to discuss this sort of thing.